# How to run drush using locally modified repo (from github fork)

Tags: drush

I have my own drush repo forked from https://github.com/drush-ops/drush and have a local clone of this, as I want to start modifying and potentially push back to add a new function. How do I configure a local drupal site to use my local repo? I have tried replacing vendor/drush with a symlink to my repo but that produced the following

```
PHP Fatal error:
Declaration of DrupalCodeGenerator\Command\DrupalGenerator::getDestination(array $vars): ?string
must be compatible with DrupalCodeGenerator\Command\GeneratorInterface::getDestination()
in /path-to-my-drush-repo/vendor/chi-teck/drupal-code-generator/src/Command/DrupalGenerator.php
 on line 141
```

I have tried tracking down the cause of that problem, but I dont think this is right way to solve it. I must be doing something else wrong. I want to contribute to drush development but getting stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the path to the local Git working copy as [a VCS repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories) in the Drupal project with a file:// URI. Specify `dev-your-branch-name` for the package version.

Comment: You can alternatively use a “path” repository type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994088/composer-require-local-package

Comment: Thanks cilefen. After I figured out that the file:// url needs three / it recognised the path     `{  
            "type": "vcs",  
            "url":  "file:///path/to/my/repo/drush/"  
        },  
`

Comment: after doing `composer update drush/drush:"11.x-dev"` it appears that I have the 11.x-dev branch, but I can't get the modified command to be found.

Comment: I have now got to the situation where the environment is recognising my new branch. Using `dev-11.x` only complained that all it could find was `11.x-dev` which was not my repo. So I checked out a new drush branch, say, `my-bugfix` and then had `require "drush/drush": "dev-my-bugfix"` and this works of sorts. I can commit to the branch and then `composer update drush/drush` and this gets my modified code. But I can't get it to simply use the latest changes without any commit and update. There must be a way to use the repo dynamically without having to commit and update every change?

Comment: You can also check out a branch of a given project in the vendor directory for real-time work.

Comment: Solved this my replacing the directory `vendor/drush/drush/src/Drupal/Commands` with a symlink to the corresponding directory in my drush git repo

Comment: ah, comments crossed, I did not see your last. Thank you.